# Excel: Copying text from 1 cell and ADDING it to the top of the cell next to it

Tags: vba, excel, text, copy

I have the following scenario:

I have about 200 rows of data and two columns. The first column contains "latest updates". The second column contains "archived updates"

Example:

[image: Example]

I want to be able to select one CELL, then click a macro button. What that would do is take the TEXT in that cell and cut it to the cell on the right, INSERTING the contents on the top of that cells contents.

The end result in the cell on the right would be TEXT from selected cell (e.g. B2) + TEXT from the original cell (e.g. C2)

Thanks!

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far, and why isn't it working?

Answer (score 0):

This'll do it. It loops on the column set as `columnChecked` and if the top entry in the cell to the right of it ("archived") does not match the "current" entry, it inserts that entry into the adjacent "archived" cell. You can/may have to adjust `sheetName`, `columnChecked`, `rowStart`, and `rowEnd` to fit your data.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim sheetName As String
    sheetName = "Sheet1"

    Dim columnChecked As String
    columnChecked = "B"

    Dim rowStart As Long
    rowStart = 2

    Dim rowEnd As Long
    rowEnd = sheets(sheetName).Range(columnChecked & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row


    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In sheets(sheetName).Range(columnChecked & rowStart & ":" & columnChecked & rowEnd).Cells
        If Split(cell.offset(0, 1).Value2, Chr(10))(0) <> cell.Value2 Then
            cell.offset(0, 1).Value2 = cell.Value2 & Chr(10) & cell.offset(0, 1).Value2
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```